# How to run a sagemaker training job with lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: Access denied for repository: trace_serial_num_outlier in registry ID: 20XXXX. Please check if your ECR repository and image exist and role arn:aws:iam::30ZZZ:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-YYY has proper pull permissions for SageMaker: ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability, ecr:BatchGetImage, ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer".

The role have SagemakerFULLAccess. How to resolve this issue?

I am trying to run a sagemaker training job with lambda function.

Comment: I added the shown permissions to ECR which this role is trying to access. It fixed this issue!